# Another word for "consume" that's clearly about incorporeal things?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a single verb with similar meaning to *gaining*, *consuming* or *gathering*, but only in a context of *information*, *knowledge* or *ideas*. So the word itself should make clear that I'm talking about immaterial goods. It shouldn't frequently be used for material goods.

Which word in the English language fits that best?

Comment: "*Consume*", traditionally, entails a sense of "using up"; that is, once you *consume* something you no longer have it (which is precisely why we say "You can't *have* your cake and *eat it* too"). By contrast, both gather and gain denote the taking and holding of objects, but *lack* the sense of "making use" (consider "to *gain* the upper hand" means you now *have* and advantage, but you have *not used it* [yet]). In other words, "*gaining*" and "*gathering*" tend to *increase* your inventory, whereas "*consuming*" tends to *deplete* it. Information bucks this trend: people *consume* news.

Comment: Since 'gather data' and 'collect information' are collocations, I doubt you'll find a word which isn't a metaphorical extension of one used literally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that there is a precise term but   [use](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Use), though  not specific to information or knowledge ,  as shown [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use%20information%2Cuse%20knowledge%2C%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0),   is quite common in this context.

To use:

> - 1. To take or consume; partake of: She rarely used her ideas.

Comment: I am not a native speaker but the usage range of *use* seems too wide to me. For example, you can *use an opportunity* as well as *use a tool*.

Comment: Yes, it a general term, but very common when talking about 'information' for instance. You may refer to the 'use' of words or to the usage of 'knowledge'.

Answer (score 0):

*Gain* and *increase* work, I think.

Comment: I think *increase* is different from *consume* in its meaning, for example *the water level increases*. What I want to express is more like *read a book* or *watch a show*. *Gain* feels better here.

Comment: Please expand your answer (by [edit]ing). As it stands it doesn't explain itself, so is not very helpful. Also *gain* is implied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some senses of *[glean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glean#Verb)* are related to farming (eg, “To collect (grain, grapes, etc.) left behind after the main harvest or gathering” and  “To gather what is left in (a field or vineyard)”.  However, another sense is in use now: “To gather information in small amounts, with implied difficulty, bit by bit”.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of incorporeal things, I actually think **implement** might come close.
Instead of implementing tools to do something, you more accurately "implement *the use* of tools". 
I tried to research this but came up short- can only concepts 'be implemented', anyone...?

Answer (score -1):

I think "*to obtain*" will fit here. Example:

> *We have **obtained** topographic measurements of the surface of Mars.*

Comment: How can this be acceptable? 'It shouldn't frequently be used for material goods.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unmarked it as accepted.